# Android Studio Error: Incompatible Java Runtime Version while Using Android Gradle Plugin

Tags: java, android, gradle

I encountered an issue while working on my Android project. During the build process, Android Studio threw the following error:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ApplicationExtensionImpl$AgpDecorated.
      > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintImpl$AgpDecorated.
         > Could not generate a decorated class for type LintImpl$AgpDecorated.
            > com/android/tools/lint/model/LintModelSeverity has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

**Project Level build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
}
```

**Java Version in Use**
JDK 11.0.13 (as indicated in the project structure; accessible via "Project Structure" > "Project" > "Gradle JDK")

How to fix this compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error arises due to a version mismatch between the JDK used by the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) and the JDK that compiled certain classes in your project. Here's a breakdown of the issue and two potential solutions:

### **Solution 1: Update JDK Version in Android Studio**

In Android Studio, go to "Project Structure" → "Project" → "Gradle" → "Gradle JDK" and choose or add a newer JDK version (like 17) that matches the requirements of the AGP version you are using.[image]

BTW this solution may cause another issue.

```
The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 8.1.1) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 7.3.0
See Android Studio & AGP compatibility options.
```

Which means that Android Studio doesn't match the newest AGPT. This link [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility) shows you that matching table Android Studio to AGP version.

Please note that modifying the JDK settings in Android Studio would only affect the current project, and it won't interfere with other projects that might be using different JDK versions.

### **Solution 2: Downgrade AGP and Related Plugins**

Modify your gradle-wrapper.properties file to specify a compatible Gradle distribution:

Before Change:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
```

After Change:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

Adjust the versions of AGP and other plugins in your project-level build.gradle file:

Before Change:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.0' apply false
}
```

After Change:

```
plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.0.4' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.0.4' apply false
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
    }
```

By downgrading, you align the AGP version with the currently set default JDK version for your project, circumventing the compatibility issues without necessitating changes to the JDK setup.

### **Understanding the Issue:**

Understanding the Issue
In Android development, it's vital to recognize the distinction between the Java version used at the application level and the JDK version that the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) utilizes during the build process. These two entities, though related, serve different purposes:

Java Version at Application Level:

This version is specified in the build.gradle file at the app module level. It dictates the version of Java used to compile the code that will run on the Android device. This version doesn't have a direct correlation with the issue at hand. Here is an example of where you might specify the Java version in the app-level build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

JDK Version Required by AGP:

The AGP, which runs on your development machine, requires a specific version of the JDK to function. This version is not necessarily the same as the Java version used to compile your application code. The error message you encountered pertains to this JDK version, which was incompatible with the AGP version you were using. Here is an example of where you might specify the AGP version in the project-level build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
}
```

Managing JDK Versions in Android Studio:

AGP versions have specific JDK version requirements. For instance, AGP version 8.0 mandates the use of JDK 17. However, you don't necessarily need to alter the global JAVA_HOME setting on your machine to meet this requirement. Android Studio allows you to specify the JDK version at the project level, meaning changes will only affect the current project and not interfere with others. You can adjust this in the Android Studio project structure settings, thereby preventing conflicts with other projects that may require different JDK versions.